# How to set channel id of FCM by notification payload in Android?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I checked already the following in [Handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages).

```
`notification` payload will be handled by the system tray.
```

So I couldn't get callback in `onMessageReceived()` so I can't create a channel for the notification.
Now, I'm using `notification` and `data` payloads together and the issue is only for the background of the app.
 It works well on what I intended in the foreground of the app.

The structure of the payload is like this.

```
"notification" : {...},
"data" : {...},
"android" : {
  "data" : {...},
  "notification" : {...}
}
```

Then how I'm able to create an appropriate channel with `notification` payload?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? The documentation around setting the channel id is appaling